# Orbits of Thompson's group

Tags: gr.group-theory, group-actions

Thompson's group may act by homeomorphisms on the circle.

Has this action a fixed point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean Thompson's $F$, please, specify the action on the circle.

If you mean Thompson's group $[F,F]$, the answer is yes, as it acts on the interval.

I think you are talking about Thompson's group $T$, and its dynamics on the circle was well described by Ghys and Sergiescu in

*[Sur un groupe remarquable de difféomorphismes du cercle.](http://www.umpa.ens-lyon.fr/~ghys/reviews/896095.pdf)*

The answer to your question is however rather trivial : the group contains every dyadic rotation, which act minimally on the circle. So every finite orbite must be dense, which is impossible.